# Сравнить две даты без учета времени

Tags: java, timestamp, java-8

У меня есть дата в `timestamp` формате. Каким образом можно проверить равна ли она текущей дате без учета времени? Например `1502010000` она равна  `6.07.2017`.

Я получил данную дату и текущую, но как сравнить не понятно:

```
Instant date= Instant.ofEpochSecond(1502010000);
Instant now = Instant.now();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java 8 представила новый механизм для работы с датами реализованный API из пакета `java.time.*`.
В данном случае для сравнения дат можно использовать следующий макет поведения:

```
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(1502010000);
LocalDateTime before = timestamp.toLocalDateTime();
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
int compareREsult = now.compareTo(before);
```

Если `compareResult` отрицательное число - если сравниваемая дата позже, положительное - если раньше и ноль если равны.

**UPD:**

Поскольку в вопросе есть неучтенное условие, что дата должна сравниваться без времени, то предлагается использоваться следующий вариант:

```
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(1502041448453l);
// System.out.println(timestamp); выведет "2017-08-06 20:44:08.453"
LocalDate localDateTime = timestamp.toLocalDateTime().toLocalDate();

LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
// System.out.println(now); выведет "2017-08-06"

// Выведет 0;
System.out.println(now.compareTo(localDateTime));
```

Comment: В данном случае должен быть 0, т.к. 1502010000 - Sunday, 6 August 2017 г., 09:00:00 и  now это 6 августа, но Ваш код выдает 47.

Comment: Наверное мы говорим о разных Timestamp. 6 Августа 2017 - это 1502041448453 в случае java.sql.Timestamp. Какой тип используете Вы?

Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(1502041448453l);
System.out.println(timestamp);

Выведет: 2017-08-06 20:44:08.453
Единственное, что я не учел в вопросе - это то, что Вы хотели осуществить сравнение без времени. Поэтому обновил ответ секцией UPD.

Answer (score 3):

Я может что-то не понял, но:

https://habrahabr.ru/post/61391/

> TIMESTAMP Хранит 4-байтное целое число, равное количеству секунд,
>   прошедших с полуночи 1 января 1970 года

И данное вами число выдает 18 января 1970, а никак не 6 августа 2017

http://www.fileformat.info/tip/java/date2millis.htm

---

Но если у вас все отлично показывает, то можете использовать Calendar и просто обнулить время

```
private static Date dateRemoveTime(Date date){
        Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        calendar.setTime(date);
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

        return calendar.getTime();
    }
```